# Can use pseudo maximum likelihood method with mixed continuous and discret data in copula

Tags: copula, empirical-likelihood, pseudo-likelihood

For copula models there are different estimation ways. One of them, is Pseudo maximum  likelihood method. In this method, the margins are estimated using empirical cumulative density function. Then copula parameters is estimated using maxim likelihood function.

Can we still use this method with mixed data (discrete and continues margins). If, yes, could you please advice me if there is any R package for this case?